# How to convert Beautiful Soup Unicode into a decimal value?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to Use python's Beautiful Soup Library to grab a bunch of divs from an html file, and from there get the string - which is a money value - that's inside the div. Then remove the dollar sign and convert it to a decimal so that I can use a greater than and less than conditional statement to compare values. I have googled the heck out of it and can't seem to come up with a way to convert this unicode string into a decimal value. I really could use some help here. How do I convert unicode into a decimal value?

This was my last attempt:

```
import unicodedata
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("/Users/sm/Documents/python/htmldemo.html"))
for tag in soup.findAll("div",attrs={"itemprop":"price"}) :
val = tag.string
new_val = val[8:]
workable = int(new_val)
if workable > 250:
    print(type(workable))
else:
    print(type(workable))
```

Edit:

When I print the type of new_val I get  :

```
print(type(new_val))
```

Comment: If it's a price, you probably want to convert it to a `float`. What happens when you do either? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Anybody care to comment as to why I am getting down-voted here? I though this website is where you go when you run into a specific programming problem and you have exhausted all other resources.

Comment: @Blender I always thought money should be a decimal value. But thinks for pointing out the float, that seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `int()` or `float()` depending if you want it to be a whole number or a number that can have a decimal point.

As far as I can tell, you are using `int()`. As you seem to think this isn't working, you probably want `float()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the value is unicode, not some BeautifulSoup internal representation? It seems that there is no problem with converting unicode to integer in python. Here is the output of Python interpreter.

```
In [2]: my_unicode = u'10'

In [3]: type(my_unicode)
Out[3]: unicode

In [4]: my_int = int(my_unicode)

In [5]: type(my_int)
Out[5]: int

In [6]: my_int > 2
Out[6]: True

In [7]: my_int > 10
Out[7]: False
```

It is possible that you have a problem with converting some BeautifulSoup internal type to integer.